# Typescript decorator replace function body or return

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to write a decorator which replace the function body or simple return from the function. Something like this:

```
function mock(target: (...args: any) => any) {
 return () => 'new hi'
}

class Greeting {
    @mock
    sayHello() {
        return 'hi'
    }
}
```

Basically I use NestJS with GraphQL and I want to replace the function body to use "mock" version in some scenarios. So this `@mock` decorator will be used along with `@Query` in resolvers.

The other trouble that I have is to recognize a mock request. I will have flag `?mock=true` in query or custom header param. Any ideas on how to check query params or headers in decorator?

Comment: If the class containing the decorated member has access to the http request, then yes. Otherwise you'll have to resort to global state

Comment: In order to have the most generic decorator possible, I would definitely suggest to follow the second option from @AluanHaddad comments.
The decorator would then take the original method body (let's call it `originalFn` and do the condition to see the replacement.

`return isRequestMocked ? mockedFn : originalFn`